# PHP - JS and CSS minifier

Tags: php, javascript, css, minify

I have a simple CSS minifier which... all it does is removes whitespace and comments. I'm rather happy with it but if there is something better - let me know.

Now for JS minifiers, I have this beast of a thing here: https://github.com/rgrove/jsmin-php/blob/master/jsmin.php of course, I have some pretty long JS scripts. I want something long, to minify rather quickly. Minifying jQuery (I know it's already got a minified) takes 2 seconds, sometimes even 4 or more! I won't have files as large of jQuery, but I may get some half as large and I doubt 1-2 seconds to load a single JS file is very attractive.

I'm wondering if there is some quick minifiers out there? I only need a minifier, I don't need something that combines, caches etc.

Comment: I read your comment on genesis's answer. If you cache the minified output, I don't understand why it matters how long it takes to minify? As I'm reading it, the 2-4 seconds only comes into play the first time you minify your packages. Subsequent calls should pull the minified code from the cache. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you're looking for this https://github.com/c9s/pecl-cssmin

Answer (score 3):

You do not need a quick minifier - just build (minify) new version of your javascript when you do changes and save it all into js file

Comment: I'd imagine OP is intending on minifying code on the go though.

Comment: @Cyclone: yes but he never can do it faster than with single js file - I think DL time will be even longer than with unminified one

Comment: I mean, the javascript code is dynamic, or based on user input or something. Obviously OP shouldn't have the code minify static js.

Comment: well I don't code in the minify version. I have packages in an xml file in which the php reads.  It'll combine all files in a package, and grab the content of each one and build it together. I minify it, cache the output... and off it goes to the browser.

I don't understand what you mean by minifying it before saving it. That just takes... effort?

Comment: So... I'm not sure what it is I'm suppose to do.

Comment: @JeanieTallis: "cache the output" do not cache it but save it as separate .js file and put it into your web to DL - it will be much faster than with php

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$js = file_get_contents($_GET['f']);
$md = md5($js); // you can use sth faster, such as date comparsion
if (file_exists('cache/'.$md.'.js')) {
  echo file_get_contents('cache/'.$md.'.js');
} else {
  $min = yourJsMinifierFunc($js);
  file_put_contents('cache/'.$md.'.js', $min);
  echo $min;
}
```

Ok, it should work for you. Once you modify your .js file, it's being minified and cached.

Comment: this is a better approach, i think im using this. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to have a look at [Assetic library](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic).
With Assetic you can manage from PHP side all of your assets applying filters as you need

Comment: It's slow, because it's symfony-based component.

Comment: @c9s it's not the Symnfony bundle. By the way once the files are generated, what's the overhead?